# SwiftUI - fill with AngularGradient or LinearGradient

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to create a View with a shape such as a Rectangle, which is either filled with a linear or an angular gradient, based on a variable.

My attempt looks like this:

```swift
struct TempTestView: View {
    @State var circleMode: Bool = true
    let gradient: Gradient = Gradient(colors: [.red, .green])
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(circleMode ? AngularGradient(gradient: gradient, center: .center) : LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
            .opacity(0.5)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)


    }
}

struct TempTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TempTestView()
    }
}
```

Swift throws me an error: 
`Cannot convert value of type 'AngularGradient' to expected argument type 'FillStyle'`

If I change the code to remove the inline if and replace it with either `AngularGradient(gradient: gradient, center: .center)` or `LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)`, swift compiles successfully.

If I try to wrap everything in a function that returns `some ShapeStyle`, swift complains that AngularGradient and LinearGradient are not of the same type. With a View I'd wrap both in `AnyView`, but I don't see an `AnyStyle` to wrap in.

My example is simplified. For animation/transition reasons, there cannot be two separate rectangle, which was why I'm looking for an inline solution like in my example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it by creating a computed property that returns the pre-formatted rectangle and using it as a view in the body. This solution is not ideal though, but at least it lets you add the view to the body and specify transitions and animations just once:

```
private var Bkgr:  AnyView {
  if circleMode {
    return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(AngularGradient(gradient: gradient, center: .center)))
  }
  return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)))
}
```

Then you can just simply add it in your body as a single view:

```
var body: some View {
  self.Bkgr
    .opacity(/*..*/)
    .transition(/*...*/)
    .animation(/**/)
    // go crazy just once
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opaque return type `some view` requires you to provide determined code. The result type must be certain, not depending of any variable or condition. This is why you can use `condition ? Result1 : Result2` operator only if Result1 and Result2 are the same type. `LinearGradient` and `AngularGradient` are not.

So, you can put whole Rectangle in If-else block. Its not a flow instruction in a runtime, its an alternative view container, like `VStack`. It will make a cortege of two Views which can have different types. Its like Schroedinger View :) Actually it is a both Views type at the same time, so swift just hide one of them according to condition.

Try something like this:

```
struct TempTestView: View {
    @State var circleMode: Bool = true
    let gradient: Gradient = Gradient(colors: [.red, .green])
    var body: some View 
        Group{
            if circleMode{
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(AngularGradient(gradient: gradient, center: .center))
            }else{
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
            }
        }
            .opacity(0.5)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }           
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but my example is over simplified. For animation/transition reasons, there cannot be two separate rectangle, which was why I'm looking for an inline solution. I'm editing my question.

Comment: then use a function that returns AnyView to create body. You can use runtime flow control there to chose witch gradient to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could try approaching this situation with a different angle.
Try to relate the Angular and the Linear gradient as views.
and place them inside a VStack as so:

```
struct TempTestView: View {
    @State var circleMode: Bool = true
    let gradient: Gradient = Gradient(colors: [.red, .green])
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if circleMode {
                AngularGradient(gradient: gradient, center: .center)
            } else {
                LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            }
        }
        .opacity(0.5)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

I tried it and it complies.

Answer (score 0):

The body must always return the same kind of view:

```swift
struct TempTestView: View {

    @State var circleMode: Bool = true
    let gradient: Gradient = Gradient(colors: [.red, .green])

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Button(action: {
                self.circleMode.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Toggle Circle Model!")
            }
            if circleMode {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(AngularGradient(gradient: gradient, center: .center))
            } else {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
            }
        }
        .opacity(0.5)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Try this code for your desired result.

Comment: Nice idea, but my example is over simplified. For animation/transition reasons, there cannot be two separate rectangles, which was why I'm looking for an inline solution. I'm editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use function to return AnyView.

```
struct TempTestView: View {
    @State var circleMode: Bool = true
    let gradient: Gradient = Gradient(colors: [.red, .green])
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            myGradient()
                .opacity(0.5)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            Button(action: {self.circleMode.toggle()}){
                Text("toggle")
            }
        }
    }
    func myGradient() -> AnyView{
        if circleMode {
            return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(AngularGradient(gradient: gradient, center: .center)))
        } else {
            return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)))
        }
    }
}
```

Its some cheating way. You hide real signature of your View from SwiftUI with AnyView container. But if works. It's just a code there in a function. You can use flow control (loops and if-else in runtime) to create AnyView.